# Node.js, Geth & Events

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs

I've been tracking a case where my Node.Js server just stop receiving events, basically for each contract, when I do a

```
contact.allEvents({ fromBlock: startblock }, (error, data) => {
...
});
```

It works, mostly. After some time events just stop. (Currently I have 3 contracts like this, it seems to happen mostly at the same time.) So what I've been doing is to reset geth and/or the process (using cluster, so can just spawn a fresh one).

However... during the last 3 days I've been monitoring my nodes via ethstats.net and it seems like my specific Geth node just starts falling behind in blocks and this seems to occur around the same time. A restart works and everything is back to normal - I'd rather not do this twice a day manually.

What tips and tricks do people have for making sure Geth keeps healthy in production so it runs 24/7?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, geth is very likely to fall behind and loose sync if it does not have sufficient cache. See [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32028/ill-never-reach-final-block-updating-with-geth-its-too-slow/32040#32040) for recommendations on how to set and choose cache size.