# I'll never reach final block updating with geth, it's too slow

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, network

I´m updating my ethereum blockchain with geth. But I feel it is going really slowly.

[image: Geth Updating]

Each block is done in 1 minute, sometimes 30 seconds, but at this pace I'll never reach the final block, because every 17 seconds there is a new block.

Basically blocks are generating at a higher speed than my geth. I'll never finish. Am I doing something wrong? Or probably is my perception and I'm going fine?

It may be a network problem, a processor problem, any tip would help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the --syncmode "fast" option for geth? Are you writing to a SSD?

Comment: When was this screenshot taken? The node looks to be about 2 days behind the newest block, so if you took this picture 2 days ago, you aren't behind, you're just getting new blocks

Comment: No, I took that snapshot at the moment I made the question.

Comment: No, it's a regular HDD.

Comment: That might be (part of) the issue. I myself had better luck on a SSD vs HDD. as well as doing a fast/light sync vs a full sync.

Comment: Is there any limitation doing the light sync?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try increasing the cache of geth using option `--cache <cache size in MB>`. This is especially important if you are no longer in fast sync mode (and your screen shot shows that you are not). Experience is that you should approximately give 30%-40% of your memory to geth. If you give more, you are likely to run into out of memory issues when you run geth continously.

Also from experience, it is recommendable to give geth a cache of around 8 GB (`--cache 8192`). This number is increasing as the blockchain inreases.

Comment: Perfect solution, and I used your recommendation of 8GB ( --cache 8192) and it reduced each block time from 1 minute average to 10 seconds average.